# Using try and catch to get the input

Tags: java

So I was just trying to create a simple program with bit more complicated code.
What I was asked to do was write a program which controls whether it's a positive or negative number (I know, it's easy).

What I was trying to do was to catch what was being entered, so if its not a `float` it will say to use a comma instead of point or enter a number instead of `String`.

```
package example1;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numbritest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    float num;

    Scanner sisse1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Sisesta number:");
        System.out.println("Kaks komakohta on lubatud");
        num = sisse1.nextFloat();
    }

    catch(InputMismatchException exception) //juhul kui sisestab miskit muud
    {
        System.out.println("Kontrolli kas kasutasid koma!");

    }

    if (num < 0) //kui arv väiksem
    {
        System.out.println("Number " +num +" on negatiivne.");
        System.out.println("Seega on arv väiksem nullist");

    }
    else //Kui arv on suurem või võrdne
    {
        System.out.println("Number " +num +" on positiivne.");
        System.out.println("Positiivsed arvud on suuremad");
        System.out.println("või võrdsed nulliga.");

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Programm lõpetada!");
  }
  }
```

Sorry that it's in Estonian, but I hope you get my point.

Comment: You question do not contain question.

Comment: Yes sorry, question is, how to get it to work?
Right now it throws some errors.
I fixed it so that if the entered float is not a float(string for example) it just gives error and ends the program.

I want it not to give the error, so the user would have another chance of entering the float.

I thought of using while, might that work?

Comment: Let me try to guess. You want analyze error and print suggestion on how to fix it before re-reading value?

Comment: Do click a tick to select an answer, if you found one helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is create a loop and ask user to input number as long as the number is not correct:
So this code:

```
try
{
    System.out.println("Sisesta number:");
    System.out.println("Kaks komakohta on lubatud");
    num = sisse1.nextFloat();
}
catch(InputMismatchException exception) //juhul kui sisestab miskit muud
{
    System.out.println("Kontrolli kas kasutasid koma!");

}
```

Should be in a loop - for example:

```
boolean incorrectNumberFormat;
do
{
    incorrectNumberFormat = false;
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Sisesta number:");
        System.out.println("Kaks komakohta on lubatud");
        num = sisse1.nextFloat();
    }

    catch(InputMismatchException exception) //juhul kui sisestab miskit muud
    {
        System.out.println("Kontrolli kas kasutasid koma!");
        sisse1.nextLine();
        incorrectNumberFormat = true;  //repeat the loop;
    } 
} while(incorrectNumberFormat);
```

By the way - comma won't generate the exception (for me `3,3` doesn't), but `3%3` should give you the exception.
The loop can be created in various ways it's just an quick example.

Answer (score 1):

Change **float num;** to **float num = 0.0f;** and it should work properly

Comment: It works so, but still gives the error, I want it to pass the error and give user another chance to enter float

Answer (score 0):

I'd change it to

```
Float num = null;
```

(note we're now using a `Float` object rather than `float` primitive, so it can be `null`) and then use a `while` condition:

```
while (num == null) {
  try {
    //...
    num = sisse1.nextFloat();
  } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    //give error
  }
}
```

This will not put anything into `num` until the `num = ...` line succeeds, so it'll stay `null` whenever it fails. This is better than just setting it to `0.0f`, because otherwise it'll cause problems if the user enters zero.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the local varible before use;
In these case compiler consider that try block may execute or not so that num.nextFloat() may execute or not so compiler throws error: variable num might not have been initialized.
 so that change float num; to float num=0.0f;